# How can I utilize source control when my working copy needs to be on a shared host without SSH access?

Tags: version-control, shared-hosting

I'm trying to develop a little toy PHP project, and the most convenient location to run it is on a shared host I happen to have for my ill-maintained blog. The problem with this is that I have no way to run Subversion on this shared host, nor do I even have SSH access to be able to access an external repository from the host. Had I been thinking straight a few months ago when the hosting was up for renewal, I probably should have paid a couple extra bucks to switch to something a bit better, but for now I can't justify throwing money at having a second host just for side projects.

This means that a working copy of my project would need to be checked out to my laptop, while the project itself would need to be uploaded to the shared host to run. My best option seems to be creating a virtual machine running Linux and developing everything from in there, but I know from past experience that the extra barrier that creates, small though it may be, is enough that it puts me off firing the VM up just to do a couple minutes work to make some minor change I just thought up. I'd much prefer to just be able to fire up my editor and get to work.

While I'd imagine I'm not the first to encounter such a problem, I haven't had much success finding a solution online. Perhaps there isn't one beyond the VM or "manual mirroring" options, but if there is I'd expect StackOverflow to be the place to find it.

---

Edit: There's some confusion, it seems, so let me attempt to clarify. **The shared host here is basically my dev server**, but it has no svn or ssh. In other words, I can `svn checkout` to my laptop, but I *can't* run that on my shared host. Similarly, I can run/test my code on the shared host, but I can't do that on my laptop (well, I technically could, but it's Windows, and I don't want to worry about Win-vs.-Linux differences with PHP, since I do want this to become public at some point, and it will certainly be Linux-based at that point).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider writing a [post-commit hook](http://www.codersrevolution.com/index.cfm/2008/9/15/Creating-a-postcommit-hook-for-Subversion) to automatically upload the code to your host, so that any time you commit a change, a script executes that:

- Checks out a copy of the code into a temporary directory
- Uploads that code via FTP (or whatever your preferred method is) to the shared host
- Cleans up after itself, optionally informing you via e.g. email when the transfer is successful

Subversion makes enough information available to these scripts at runtime that you could get more sophisticated and opt only to upload the files that changed or alter behavior based on specific property changes, for instance, but for a small project the brute force "copy it all" approach should be fine.

Comment: there are hooks in Git as well.

Comment: As do Mercurial, Perforce, and most other version control systems - the general idea of the solution would work across the board, though the original poster specifically mentioned Subversion, so that's what I went with

Comment: Post-commit is only part of this though. Since the working copy is on another server without SSH, I can't do anything like `svn diff` or `svn info`. I'd have to move everything back to the local working copy whenever I wanted to run even a trivial command. If this is the best option, I'd sooner deal with the VM than have to FTP everything back and forth all the time. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your situation. In the method I outlined above, you'd have your working copy checked out on your laptop, where you would make any edits to files, then commit the change to your version control. From there, the process by which it made it to your server would be wholly automated, and there should never be any reason for the data to 'flow the other direction' back from your hosting service, since the only place you would be making changes would be your local machine. Where would your repository itself be hosted?

Comment: Yeah, you're definitely misunderstanding. The shared host is the dev server in this situation (there is no production really, at least not at this point). Since the 'dev server' is a shared host, I can't have the actual working copy there, so I need an easy way to keep a local "svn working copy" and a remote "development *working-on-it* copy" in sync. Basically, I can only `svn checkout` to my laptop, but I can't run the code there. I can run code on the shared host, but I can't `svn checkout` there. Does that clarify the problem a bit?

Comment: I think the piece of the situation I'm not understanding right now is where your actual Subversion repository lives. When you do `svn checkout` on your laptop, where is the code coming from?

Comment: There is no repo at this point, but I don't see how that factors into the issue. It could be on my laptop, or github, or even a USB drive. It doesn't even have to be svn. I've never used git or hg before, so I'm just using what I know. The repo is just a database somewhere that you query. What's at issue is where you run `svn checkout`, not where the code comes from when you do. In my case, I *can't* run `svn checkout` from the shared host, since I have no shell access at all. I would have to run it from my laptop, so the working copy would be created on my laptop rather than the shared host.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you run `svn checkout` on your shared host; the entire goal of the answer I gave was to dance around having to do that. I'm 95% sure I understand your problem and that my solution is pretty workable, but I'm clearly not expressing myself well. Maybe @devin-ceartas or someone else would like to chime in?

Comment: @SchiefGelaufen let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2177/discussion-between-agentconundrum-and-schiefgelaufen)